# Why does this string implementation allocate one more character than there are characters in the string?

Tags: c++, string, memory, null-terminated

```
String::String(const String& old_str)    
{ 
    size = old_str.size; 
    s = new char[size+1];
```

Why do we use `size+1` here to allocate memory, not `size`?

Comment: Probably to make space for the terminating `\0` character.

Answer (score 2):

In C, strings all end with a null-byte, represented by `\0` inside a string. The `size` attribute returns the size not accounting for the nullbyte, so you must allocate `size+1` bytes so the terminating nullbyte doesn't overflow. Read more about null-terminated strings [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string).